# Getting snapshot error while executing maven command

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm getting up below snapshot error while executing of maven command

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.amadeus.maven.plugins:cb-release-maven-plugin:1.9.3:prepare (default-cli) on project XXXXX : 
        Maven version should be a SNAPSHOT version and end with -SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

And this is the maven command

```
sh 'mvn -X --update-snapshots --quiet cb-release:prepare  -DbranchingModel="master.*:@{VERSION}.@{BUILD},release/.*:@{VERSION}.@{BUILD},sync.*:@{VERSION}.@{BUILD},hotfix/.*:@{VERSION}.@{BUILD},.*:@{BRANCH}-@{VERSION}.@{BUILD}"'
```

I am currently migrating my repositories to softwareWorkBench so before to that above maven command was working fine.
But now when I am trying to give these commands in Jenkinsfile its failing with above error.

In my pom file, `<version>` tag is like this

```
<version>1-SNAPSHOT<version>
```

Please suggest how it can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

AS a suggestion, for testing, check if a POM with a version using `major.monor.patch` would work better

```
1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

If you have multiple modules, make sure all your `pom.xml` have the same version.

Comment: Hello @VonC - I updated version as 1.0.0 Snapshot but i am getting error as below 

Non-resolvable parent POM for com.amadeus.uf.jboss_standard:docker:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact com.amadeus.uf:jboss_standard:pom:1-SNAPSHOT in central  and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 3, column 10

And there are not multiple modules for this repository.

Comment: @vikashsrivastava Do you have a `<parent>` element?

Comment: There is no parent element in pom .

Comment: @vikashsrivastava Then it should not try to resolve anything. Can you reference your pom.xml somewhere, for me to have a look?